# Why logical operator on character vs numeric returns TRUE/FALSE?

Tags: r

Please see below example. Logical operator `<` works with chracter and numeric, and that in some case it returns `TRUE`.  I'm cofused becase in my sense it should return `NA` or at least `FALSE`. Is this by R design ?
And I'd be grateful if you show me an simple alternative method. (I can solve this problem using custom function checking class before logical judgement. Are there better solutions ?)

```
"(abc" < 0              # TRUE
"(abc" < -1             # FALSE
"abc" < 9999999999      # FALSE
"abc" < Inf             # TRUE
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely R is performing a character conversion of the RHS of your inequalities.  That is, R is actually making the following comparisons:

```
"(abc" < "0"
"(abc" < "-1"
"abc" < "999999999"
"abc" < Inf

[1] TRUE
[1] FALSE
[1] FALSE
[1] TRUE
```

Note that the outputs agree with your current output, which uses number literals on the RHS.

Comment: Thanks for your answer !  On my env, `"(abc" < "0"` returns `TRUE`, maybe a copy and paste mistake ?

Comment: `"(abc" < "0"` definitely returns `FASLE`, at least on the demo tool I am using.  Maybe there could be a character set/encoding issue here, I don't know.

Comment: `"(abc" < "0"` returns `TRUE` for me as well and I guess that is mostly because `"(" < "0"` is `TRUE`.

Comment: @Ronak Yeah...I think it should since `(` comes before `0` in the ASCII character tables, and `(` is lexicographically "less" than `0`.  Not sure about the tool I am using.@